# How to get all of the collection ids from document on Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I connect the database from React Native project.

In my Firestore database `Buildings/Taipei`, i want to get all of the collection ids like `201` `202` `203`
[image]

I try to use the code:

```
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();

    db.collection('Buildings').doc('Taipei')
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      console.log('get doc is =>');
      console.log(doc);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(`error is ${error}`);
    });
```

I can't see any collection id in the `doc`.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want to do is not currently possible in the mobile/web client.

> The getCollections() method of the Cloud Firestore server client
>   libraries lists all subcollections of a document reference.
>
> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web
>   client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of
>   administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that
>   you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider
>   restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

Source: [List Subcollections of Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i get it now. I will try to re-structure the database. Thank you.