# Using Flutter Firestore plug in, do something for each sub collection in a document

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

To help me better understand Flutter and Firebase, I'm making a list sharing app. I'm working on the list home screen that will show a reorderable list tile view with a tile for each of the users' lists, I have not began to work on whats inside of these lists. I have firestore set up so that each list is a sub collection, now I want to create a tile for each sub collection in that user's document ( a list of that user's lists). I'm having a tough time telling flutter to do something for each sub collection without using a specific sub collection's name. I wanted to pass in a list title to each tile by making a collection reference for each sub collection( list) and calling .id on each one. Using the collection ID as the title, I'm not yet sure if I can do this or if ill have to make the list title a field inside of each list. Either way, I need to find out how to do something for each subcollection inside a particular document. .forEach seems to only work on document fields, not subcollections? What am I doing wrong? I'm sure there is a better way to go about this. I have not included any code as this is a big picture kind of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method in the Firestore client-side SDKs to get all collections (or subcollections under a specific document). Such API *does* exist in the server-side SDKs, but not in the client-side SDKs.

See:

- [Fetching all collections in Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258632/fetching-all-collections-in-firestore)
- [How to get all of the collection ids from document on Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164182/how-to-get-all-of-the-collection-ids-from-document-on-firestore)

So you'll need to *know* the collections already, typically by changing your data model. For example by creating a **document** for each list's metadata, and then storing the list *items* in a subcollection with a known name under that document. That way you can get all lists by querying for the documents, which is possible within the API.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Unfortunately, it won't let me up vote you with my current reputation.