# Flutter & Firebase: Return list of collections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Can't find any information on this, because the answer already on here to use "listCollections()" or "getCollections()" are not even valid methods.

I have a database set up like so:

```
Layout:  Collection -> Document -> Collection -> Documents
  Example Data:
  Stores  -> UID  -> StoreName1 -> 
                     StoreName2 -> 
                     StoreName3 ->
```

And so given that I know Stores and the UID, I should easily be able to return all the store names above.   There has to be a line of code that will give me the results:   StoreName1, StoreName2 & StoreName3.

Here is what I have:

```
CollectionReference documents = (await Firestore.instance.collection('Stores').document(widget.currentUserUID).    <---- now what?   There is no getCollections, there is no listCollections.   How can I return this information?
```

### Edit

So after discussing this with Peter below I have tried to work through an adjusted approach but it seems horrifically messy. Is there a better way of doing this?   Feels wrong.  Let me start with the new design:

```
Layout:  Collection -> Document -> Collection -> Documents
  Example Data:
  Stores  -> UID  -> StoresList -> Store1
                                    store_name: 'My Place'
                                   Store2
                                    store_name: 'Bellagio'
                                   Store3
                                    store_name: 'Grand Hotel'
```

So you can see that Store1, Store2 and Store3 above are documents and that they have fields, one of which is store_name.

I am trying to present the user with a list of the Stores they have under their account.   The way I am having to do this, not knowing how many stores each user may want to operate, is as follows

```
storeCount == 0 ? SizedBox()
              :
storeCount == 1 ? Container(
  child: uid == null ? LoadingAnimation() : StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('StoresList').document('Store1').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    }
    if (snapshot.data.data == null) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
        _buildStoresList(context, snapshot.data),
       );
     }
   },
 )) :
storeCount == 2 ? Container(
  child: uid == null ? LoadingAnimationBasic() : StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('StoresList').document('Store1').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    }
    if (snapshot.data.data == null) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          _buildStoresList(context, snapshot.data),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
Container(
  child: uid == null ? LoadingAnimationBasic() : StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('StoresList').document('Store2').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    }
    if (snapshot.data.data == null) {
      return LoadingAnimationBasic();
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
          _buildStoresList(context, snapshot.data),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
) : SizedBox(),
```

And then the _buildStoresList function:

```
  Widget _buildStoresList(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
    storeName = document['store_name'];
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        storeName,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Petita',
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 60,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So basically, first counting how many stores a user has (by counting the number of documents in the StoresList collection during initState() using a Future.delayed workaround to populate this correctly).   Once I have the number of stores, the only way I can see to get the data from each document is to do that above with horrible nested if statements.

What have I got wrong here?  Or is this the only way to do it?

I guess the main question is regarding this line:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('StoresList').document('Store1').snapshots(),
```

Where I need to give a specific document in order to snapshot the fields.  It would be infinitely more efficient to have a line that took the snapshot of *all* documents in the collection and not just one at a time like this.   Otherwise if the user wants to manage 200 stores, this 'if statement' nest is going to be insane.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164182/how-to-get-all-of-the-collection-ids-from-document-on-firestore

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I am not sure what this means.   You are saying this is not possible?   If so, I cannot accept that.   This is an extremely basic concept of databases, being able to retrieve the data you enter into it.   If I cannot perform this most extreme basic of functions, then there is literally no reason that Firebase exists at all.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document Basically in the client its not available to do this. You cant get a list of collection names.. Do the storenames belong to the uid?

Comment: Yeah so basically the UID is how I differentiate users, which is pretty textbook.   For each user they can create and manage as many stores as they like.  The part of the app I am working in is where it will return the current store names to the user.  Under each store name from this point will sit documents based on data category (since only documents can have fields), so for example store information, products, image references (since again, firebase is awful and I can also not even return lists of images). I don't understand how they can possibly design a database this way, it is moronic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the database to the following:

```
Stores (Collection) --> UID (Document) --> Stores (Collection) --> StoreName_1 (Document) 
                                                                   StoreName_2 (Document)
```

Then you can do:

```
var documents = await Firestore.instance.collection('Stores').document(widget.currentUserUID).collection("Stores").getDocuments();
```

This will get you all the `Stores` under one user.

Comment: But under the store names I then need sections of data.   So after StoreName1:  -> Info -> Field1, Field2, Field3.    Then StoreName1 -> Opening Hours -> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.   Then StoreName1 -> ImageGallery ->  URL1, URL2, URL3.

Comment: I guess if this is the only way to do this though, I will have to just make up random Collection names at certain points, so I can push the information into being a document instead.   This is insane, but I will try it.

Comment: Under storename1 which is a document, why can't you just add the info there (in the fields of that document)? Why are you doing a subcollection called info

Comment: Because I don't want to have 2000 data fields all lumped together.   That might be fine for machines but that's not how an organised human mind works.   Need things to be separated out and be neat, organised and sensible.

Comment: You can use an array inside the document, so if the info is always 3 fields then add it in an array, if the opening hours can also be in an array. You can use maps and arrays inside the document

Comment: That would be well and good, but the user in many cases can add as many items as they like, which is why I need to return the list, they could manage 0, 1 or hundreds of stores.  They might have 0 or hundreds of images, 0 or hundreds of menu items.  And so forth.  I'll work on this tonight and let you know how I get on, will accept solution if this works fine.

Comment: Ok I have been trying to get this working, but it seems I have to know the name of the document to be able to return the data from it, so if this is true, then this whole database system that google have created is even more terrible than initially thought.   Am I wrong?   If I have a collection of 'unknown' documents, can I reference them somehow?

Comment: Trying to make do with this database but I am now running into some more issues in trying to get this working.  I will add this to the original question to see if you have any ideas.

Comment: Got it all working, I think.  Have updated my question to include the full solution to help others who might be lost.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted an answer on behalf of the question author, in order to move it to the answer space)*.

I have worked this out, it is much simpler than nesting if statements like I was originally trying.

So the database layout is exactly the same, and you can only pull data back out of documents, not collections, so make sure you structure your databases with this in mind.

You can return all the documents from a collection like this:

```
Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('StoresList').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return LoadingAnimationBasic();  //This is a custom animation, you can use SizedBox() or anything you like here.
      }
      if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return LoadingAnimationBasic();
      } else {
        return ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: _buildStoresList(snapshot),  //Here we are chucking the whole collection snapshot into a ListView builder.  This sends all the documents in the collection in this direction.
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

And then the function that handles all those documents is pretty straight-forward:

```
  _buildStoresList(AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    return snapshot.data.documents
        .map((doc) => ListTile(
          title: Center(child: Text(doc['store_name'])),   //store_name is one of the fields inside my documents inside the collection on which I took the snapshots.
          subtitle: Center(child: Text(doc['about']))  //about is another such field.
    ))
        .toList();
  }
```

That's it.